# MySQL get the column name from column value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there is a way MySQL to get the column names given the value of the column?

For example I have `STATES` table and `CITY` table which have `'NAME'` as column name.

Say I have `'New York'` in both `STATES` table and `CITY` table. I want a query which will return the column names of `SATES` and `CITY` give `'New York'`.

My Expected Output could be like

value                    column            Table 
-----                      ------                 -----  
New York           NAME            STATES  
New York           NAME            CITY

Above is just an example. In most of the cases i only know the column values and i dont know the Column names or the corresponding table Names. Generally I need not know on the diffrent random schema's. I am building a question answersing system that will work with multiple databases.

Comment: To avoid getting answers that don't meet your requirements, perhaps you can enlighten us with more info like your expected output, some data, and table structures.. :)

Comment: What I think you're looking for can be done with a `CASE` statement, but please give an example of your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When querying, to help prevent ambiguity, always qualify the fields with alias.column such as

```
select states.name,
       city.name as CityName
   from
      city
         join states
           on city.stateabbrev = states.stateabbrev
   where
      city.name = 'New York'
```

Answer (score 0):

you must be specified the column name to select data,

get column name,you can run SQL query:

```
desc tablename
```

or using like `ResultSetMetaData`(in java)